# How does local initialization with Parallel ForEach work?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am unsure about the use of the local init function in Parallel.ForEach, as described in the msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997393.aspx

```
Parallel.ForEach<int, long>(nums, // source collection
   () => 0, // method to initialize the local variable
   (j, loop, subtotal) => // method invoked by the loop on each iteration
   {
      subtotal += nums[j]; //modify local variable 
      return subtotal; // value to be passed to next iteration
   },...
```

How does () => 0 initialize anything? What's the name of the variable and how can I use it in the loop logic?

Comment: () => doesn't initialize anything, return value of that function will be used to initialize the local variable (subtotal, in your example).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With reference to the [following overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Parallel.ForEach` static extension method:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource, TLocal>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> taskBody,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

**In your specific example**

The line:

```
() => 0, // method to initialize the local variable
```

is simply a lambda (anonymous function) which will return the constant integer zero. This lambda is passed as the `localInit` parameter to `Parallel.ForEach` - since the lambda returns an integer, it has type `Func<int>` and type `TLocal` can be inferred as `int` by the compiler (similarly, `TSource` can be inferred from the type of the collection passed as parameter `source`)

The return value (0) is then passed as the 3rd parameter (named `subtotal`) to the `taskBody` `Func`. This (0) is used the initial seed for the body loop:

```
(j, loop, subtotal) =>
{
    subtotal += nums[j]; //modify local variable (Bad idea, see comment)
    return subtotal;     // value to be passed to next iteration
}
```

This second lambda (passed to `taskBody`) is called N times, where N is the number of items allocated to this task by the TPL partitioner.

Each subsequent call to the second `taskBody` lambda will pass the new value of `subTotal`, effectively calculating a running **partial** total, for this Task. After all the items assigned to this task have been added, the third and last, `localFinally` function parameter will be called, again, passing the final value of the `subtotal` returned from `taskBody`. Because several such tasks will be operating in parallel, there will also need to be a final step to add up all the partial totals into the final 'grand' total. However, because multiple concurrent tasks (on different Threads) could be contending for the `grandTotal` variable, it is important that changes to it are done in a thread-safe manner.

(I've changed names of the MSDN variables to make it more clear)

```
long grandTotal = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(nums,            // source collection
  () => 0,                        // method to initialize the local variable
  (j, loop, subtotal) =>          // method invoked by the loop on each iteration
     subtotal + nums[j],          // value to be passed to next iteration subtotal
  // The final value of subtotal is passed to the localFinally function parameter
  (subtotal) => Interlocked.Add(ref grandTotal, subtotal)
```

*In the MS Example, modification of the parameter subtotal inside the task body is a poor practice, and unnecessary. i.e. The code `subtotal += nums[j]; return subtotal;` would be better as just `return subtotal + nums[j];` which could be abbreviated to the lambda shorthand projection `(j, loop, subtotal) => subtotal + nums[j]`*

**In General**

The `localInit / body / localFinally` overloads of [Parallel.For / Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) allow *once-per task* initialization and cleanup code to be run, before, and after (respectively) the `taskBody` iterations are performed by the Task.

(Noting the For range / Enumerable passed to the parallel `For` / `Foreach` will be partitioned into batches of `IEnumerable<>`, each of which will be allocated a Task)

In **each Task**, `localInit` will be called once, the `body` code will be repeatedly invoked, once per item in batch (`0..N` times), and `localFinally` will be called once upon completion.

In addition, you can pass any state required for the duration of the task (i.e. to the `taskBody` and `localFinally` delegates) via a generic `TLocal` return value from the `localInit Func` - I've called this variable `taskLocals` below.

**Common uses of "localInit":**

- Creating and initializing expensive resources needed by the loop body, like a database connection or a web service connection.
- Keeping Task-Local variables to hold (uncontended) running totals or collections
- If you need to return multiple objects from `localInit` to the `taskBody` and `localFinally`, you can make use of a strongly typed class, a `Tuple<,,>` or, if you use only lambdas for the `localInit / taskBody / localFinally`, you can also pass data via an anonymous class. Note if you use the return from `localInit` to share a reference type among multiple tasks, that you will need to consider thread safety on this object - immutability is preferable.

**Common uses of the "localFinally" Action:**

- To release resources such as `IDisposables` used in the `taskLocals` (e.g. database connections, file handles, web service clients, etc)
- To aggregate / combine / reduce the work done by each task back into shared variable(s). These shared variables will be contended, so thread safety is a concern:

  - e.g. `Interlocked.Increment` on primitive types like integers
  - `lock` or similar will be required for write operations
  - Make use of the [concurrent collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) to save time and effort.

The `taskBody` is the `tight` part of the loop operation - you'll want to optimize this for performance.

This is all best summarized with a commented example:

```
public void MyParallelizedMethod()
{
    // Shared variable. Not thread safe
    var itemCount = 0; 

    Parallel.For(myEnumerable, 
    // localInit - called once per Task.
    () => 
    {
       // Local `task` variables have no contention 
       // since each Task can never run by multiple threads concurrently
       var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connstring...");
       sqlConnection.Open();

       // This is the `task local` state we wish to carry for the duration of the task
       return new 
       { 
          Conn = sqlConnection,
          RunningTotal = 0
       }
    },
    // Task Body. Invoked once per item in the batch assigned to this task
    (item, loopState, taskLocals) =>
    {
      // ... Do some fancy Sql work here on our task's independent connection
      using(var command = taskLocals.Conn.CreateCommand())
      using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(...))
      {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
           // No contention for `taskLocal`
           taskLocals.RunningTotal += Convert.ToInt32(reader["countOfItems"]);
        }
      }
      // The same type of our `taskLocal` param must be returned from the body
      return taskLocals;
    },
    // LocalFinally called once per Task after body completes
    // Also takes the taskLocal
    (taskLocals) =>
    {
       // Any cleanup work on our Task Locals (as you would do in a `finally` scope)
       if (taskLocals.Conn != null)
         taskLocals.Conn.Dispose();

       // Do any reduce / aggregate / synchronisation work.
       // NB : There is contention here!
       Interlocked.Add(ref itemCount, taskLocals.RunningTotal);
    }
```

And more examples:

[Example of per-Task uncontended dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31036093/314291)

[Example of per-Task database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774265/c-sharp-multiple-parallel-inserts-in-database)

Comment: Remove the DB example and replace with a CPU -bound example. Using Parallel.For with databases probably isn't a good idea - async / await and parallelism through `Task.WhenAll` is preferable.

Answer (score 7):

as an extension to [@Honza Brestan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831399/424963)'s answer. The way Parallel foreach splits the work into tasks can also be important, it will group several loop iterations into a single task so in practice `localInit()` is called once for every n iterations of the loop and multiple groups can be started simultaneously.

The point of a `localInit` and `localFinally` is to ensure that a parallel foreach loop can combine results from each itteration into a single result without you needing to specify lock statements in the `body`, to do this you must provide an initialisation for the value you want to create (`localInit`) then each `body` itteration can process the local value, then you provide a method to combine values from each group (`localFinally`) in a thread-safe way.

If you don't need localInit for synchronising tasks, you can use lambda methods to reference values from the surrounding context as normal without any problems. See [Threading in C# (Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach)](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Parallel.For_and_Parallel.ForEach) for a more in depth tutorial on using localInit/Finally and scroll down to **Optimization with local values**, Joseph Albahari is really my goto source for all things threading.

Comment: Up voting this because this really clarified things for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a hint on MSDN in the **[correct `Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783634.aspx)** overload.

> The localInit delegate is invoked once for each thread that participates in the loop's execution and returns the initial local state for each of those tasks. These initial states are passed to the first body invocations on each task. Then, every subsequent body invocation returns a possibly modified state value that is passed to the next body invocation.

In your example `() => 0` is a delegate just returning `0`, so this value is used for the first iteration on **each task**.

Comment: I had read that text before posting here, yet, my question remains the same. How does using a lambda that just returns 0 provide me with a value that "is used for the first iteration on each task"? How can I use this value in the code? It has no identifier.

Comment: It has - it is the `subtotal` in your example. But only in the first iteration in each task. The value of `subtotal` in all other iterations in that task is what is returned from the previous iteration.

Comment: Ok, I follow you so far, but what part of this code indicates that "() => 0" = subtotal? What's the convention between the init function and (j, loop, subtotal) declaration?

Edit: I just figured it out, the devil is in the details, or in this case, in the names of the generic parameters of the body function System.Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal>. Thanks, I will mark yours as answer.

Comment: Glad you found that out, seems my answers are sometimes still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

From my side a little bit more easier example

```
class Program
{
    class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    static List<Person> GetPerson() => new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { Id = 0, Name = "Artur", Age = 26 },
        new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Edward", Age = 30 },
        new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Krzysiek", Age = 67 },
        new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "Piotr", Age = 23 },
        new Person() { Id = 4, Name = "Adam", Age = 11 },
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = GetPerson();
        int ageTotal = 0;

        Parallel.ForEach
        (
            persons,
            () => 0,
            (person, loopState, subtotal) => subtotal + person.Age,
            (subtotal) => Interlocked.Add(ref ageTotal, subtotal)
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"Age total: {ageTotal}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```